# How can I get output to 'stream' its output in the Resharper unit test session viewer instead of dumping it at the end of the test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper, xunit

I'm using

- Visual Studio 2015 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3)
- Resharper Ultimate 2018.2.3 (build 2018-09-12)
- Windows 10 x64 v1803
- .NET Framework 4.5.2

What I want is to be able to run a unit test in the resharper unit test runner and have the output STREAM to the output window.

(By the by, part of the reason why this is so important to me is because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792978/is-there-a-good-way-to-manage-running-multiple-arbitrary-c-sharp-entrypoints-in). So yes, it is a little bit of unit test abuse but unfortunately I still haven't found a good system to replace it.)

What I've tried:

**NUnit**

1. Create new console project (target framework .NET Framework 4.5.2)
2. Nuget install NUnit 3.11.0
3. Create a unit test:

   ```
   [Test]
   public void HelloWorld()
   {
       Debug.Listeners.Add(new DefaultTraceListener());
       Console.WriteLine("asdf");
       Debug.WriteLine("asdf");
       Thread.Sleep(10000);
       Console.WriteLine("asdf2");
       Debug.WriteLine("asdf2");
   }
   ```

When I run this, it only displays the output when the test has fully completed, 10 seconds in. What I want is to show the first 'asdf' basically immediatelly.

The random things I've tried were from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092438/using-resharper-how-to-show-debug-output-during-a-long-running-unit-test/15113848).

From what I can tell the Unit Test Runner doesn't even look like it is ready to begin to accepting output after the test is running. Mid-way through it looks like this:

[image]

At that point it is doing the `Thread.Sleep`. I would hope to see `asdf`

Once it is done it looks like this:

[image]

I know that in the past this used to work as I desired but this was with probably older versions of all the software (Visual Studio, Resharper, .NET Framework, NUnit)

**xUnit**
1. Create new console project
2. Nuget install NUnit 3.11.0
3. Create a unit test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void HelloWorld()
    {
        Debug.Listeners.Add(new DefaultTraceListener());
        Console.WriteLine("asdf");
        Debug.WriteLine("asdf");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("asdf2");
        Debug.WriteLine("asdf2");
    }
```

In this one I don't get any output at all.

[image]

I guess this may be related to the bug alluded to in the previous post, but it is different in that he at least gets something. The fact that I am experiencing the behaviour he is related to when he uses xUnit but I use NUnit, but that I experience different behaviour when I use xUnit is a little nonplussing to me.

My use case is hardly complex here, as I have done little more than create a brand new project, add packages and then try to use it. Is there a way I can reliably get this working?

Comment: If you use NUnit or xUnit console runners, do they behave as you expect? Because if they don't, there's no way you're going to get ReSharper do that as it consumes what a unit test framework feeds to it.